# Customize output of MATLAB's spectrogram function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, spectrogram

I would like to know whether it is possible to customize the plot generated by MATLAB's `spectrogram` function in such a way that its x-axis does not represent the time but another physical signal `y2`captured simultaneously with the input signal `y1` (used for computing the spectrogram). Therefore, it can be assumed that `y1` and `y2` have the same timestamps as x-axis as in the following example.

```
N = 1024;
n = 0:N-1;
w0 = 2*pi;
y1 = sin(w0*n);
y2 = n;
spectrogram(y1,'yaxis');
```

Answer (score 0):

To control the scale of the axes arbitrarily, you could manually plot the spectrogram using `imagesc`. Here's how:

```
N = 1024;
n = 0:N-1;
w0 = 2*pi/10;
y1 = sin(w0*n);
y2 = n;

% compute spectrogram
[s,w,t]=spectrogram(y1,'yaxis');

% find values in y2 corresponding to spectrogram time-grid
t2 = interp1((1:N), y2, t);

% use imagesc to plot spectrogram
figure;
imagesc(t2,w/pi,10*log10(abs(s.^2)/length(w)/pi))
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
colorbar;
ylabel('Normalized Frequency (\times \pi rad/sample)');
% caxis([-160, 20]) % manually tweak the color range for best detail
```

Note that I have made two minor changes to your code:

1. Changed `w0` from `2*pi` to `2*pi/10`, because the former results in `y1` being all zeros.
2. Changed `y2` to be something else than `1:N`, which is spectrogram default.

I should also point out that the built-in `spectrogram` plot does let you control the axes scale in a variety of ways, including specifying the [sample rate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html#bupbguq).